# Manual Regeneration On Workshared Cloud Models Revit API

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I'm working on an add-in that generates a number of complex 2D and 3D views and sheets (shopdrawings for fabrication). The number of views ranges from around 10 all the way up to 100+ views and sheets.

Using **Manual Regeneration** and only updating when necessary makes this tool very efficient, but when I tried deploying in on a workshared model, it appears the tool reverts to using **Automatic Regeneration**. This causes a large number of "Generating graphics for 3D View / Sections / Elevation" processes and increases the runtime greatly.

Am I missing something in the functionality of manual regeneration? Is it possible on a workshared model that is on the cloud?

I've tried looking into others' experience with this, but have yet to find anyone else experiencing this problem. The code works perfectly on local files but doesn't work when they are workshared and on the cloud.

Please let me know if you have experience in this matter.

Thanks in advance!

Noam